In Sadi's Bustan, is sweet wormwood Korean worm wood?
The Bustan, Persian: بوستان, translated as "The Orchard", is a book of poetry by the Persian poet Sadi of Shiraz (سعدی شیرازی), completed in 1257 of the current era.

A translation is provided below...

They are mendicants who fly from worldly sovereignty, possibly ingesting flying herbs, or drugs.
In the hope of dying, or meeting with god, the mendicants are patient in their mendicity.
Oft have they drunk of
the wine of anguish; be it bitter, they remain silent.
In the remembrance
of Him patience is not bitter, for Wormwood is sweet from the hand of a
friend.


Artemisia princeps, also commonly called Korean wormwood, is a species in the sunflower family, native to Asia. It is often baked into green-coloured Korean rice cakes.

Is it possible that the word "friend" refers to Asiatic peoples?
Perhaps Asiatic Wormwood is sweeter in flavor than the varieties of wormwood that historically grew near the city of Shiraz (شیراز) in Persia?

The translation is due to A. Hart Edwards but can you explain where "possibly ingesting flying herbs, or drugs" comes from? Is this your own gloss on the text?

The question seems to be premised on a misunderstanding. When the poet writes, “for wormwood is sweet from the hand of a friend”, the point is that the taste of wormwood is bitter, but the effect is sweet (pleasing) if one knows that it is a gift from the hand of a friend. This is a metaphor for the patient acceptance of suffering, knowing that it comes from the will of “Him” (that is, God).
